# Android Device Policy Manager not working

Tags: java, android, xml, lockscreen, device-policy-manager

I'm trying to make a simple app that'll lock the screen of the device when an incoming call is accepted. For this, I'm made a custom device admin with the help of [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html) tutorial. But, when I click the "Enable" button in my app, the Device Policy Manager activity does not open at all! And I get output in the logcat window that says that my `ComponentName` is invalid. However, I do not find any problems in my project what so ever!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.swap.delay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
ActivityManager activityManager;
ComponentName componentName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    componentName = new ComponentName(this, LockAdmin.class);

}

public void OnClickActivate(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Lock Admin by Swap");

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lock Admin by Swap added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

LockAdmin.java

```
package com.swap.delay;

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LockAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver{

static SharedPreferences getSamplePreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(DeviceAdminReceiver.class.getName(), 0);
}

static String PREF_PASSWORD_QUALITY = "password_quality";
static String PREF_PASSWORD_LENGTH = "password_length";
static String PREF_MAX_FAILED_PW = "max_failed_pw";

void showToast(Context context, CharSequence message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    showToast(context, "Lock Admin Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
    showToast(context, "Lock Admin: Wrong Password");
}

@Override
public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //showToast(context, "Sample Device Admin: pw succeeded");
}

}
```

policies.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/auto">
<uses-policies>
    <force-lock>
    </force-lock>
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Receiver(Added to manifest.xml)

```
<receiver android:name=".LockAdmin" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/policies">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED">
                </action></intent-filter>
        </meta-data></receiver>
```

Logcat output -

```
08-25 12:52:40.103     652-1906/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN cmp=com.android.settings/.DeviceAdminAdd (has extras)} from uid 10172 on display 0
08-25 12:52:40.162     652-1070/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.android.settings for activity com.android.settings/.DeviceAdminAdd: pid=6313 uid=1000 gids={41000, 9997, 3002, 3001, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1000, 1021, 3004, 3005, 3009, 1023, 1010, 1007} abi=arm64-v8a
08-25 12:52:40.332    6313-6313/? W/DeviceAdminAdd﹕ Request to add invalid device admin: ComponentInfo{com.swap.delay/com.swap.delay.LockAdmin}
```

P.s. - I tested out the app on two different devices on based on AOSP KitKat(4.4.2) and another one CyanogenOS 12.0(5.0.2), it didn't work on either of them.

Comment: What if you provide the fully qualified class name in your receiver declaration? `<receiver android:name="com.swap.delay.LockAdmin" ...`

Comment: @fiddler Didn't help...

Comment: Hum, what if you provide the application's context instead of the activity? `new ComponentName(this.getApplication(), LockAdmin.class);`

Comment: @fiddler No... still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, then you should put a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DeviceAdminAdd.java#L170) and see why you get this error.

Comment: @fiddler I've never done that before. Do you know any online guide or something that can help me?

Comment: No sorry, and I don't have any dev environment here to reproduce the error. Maybe someone will spot the issue and post the answer.

Comment: That blog post is really quite old - it might be worth trying out the official [Android sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#sample) for a device admin App

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: @Aun I did find a solution to this. I just had to add a few extra lines of code to my app's manifest which I learnt from the official documentation. I was thinking of adding it as answer but then I got busy and later on I forgot about it.

Comment: can you share that few lines :-)

Comment: @Aun At the moment, I don't exactly remember which lines to add, but, [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) should help you. :)

Comment: kindly try and get the detail which is missed out.  It could be just a glance for you, rather than me trying lot of trial and error

Comment: Better make your app device admin via shell command. Disable screen/ lock screen can be done after that simply.

in your case:

adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.swap.delay/.LockAdmin

Note:- you can only disable device admin programatically, call these dpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp("com.swap.delay")